# Did anyone install vmware server (the free edition ) on Windows 7 (x64)?

Tags: windows-7, vmware-server

I would like to upgrade my station to 7 (x64) but I must run the vmware, I wonder if anyone had tried it already ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, it works.

BTW, your question belongs on superuser